# Array of dates prints unexpected dates in moment js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs, momentjs

In my code snippet, moment js is not giving the expected result.

`weekStart` is set to start of the week (ie **19th** Jul ) and `weekEnd` is set to end of the week (ie. **25th Jul**).

while printing individually both are printing the correct dates, but when it is used from an array(`validRange`),  `weekStart` is printing **25th Jul** instead of **19th Jul**.

Is there any solution for this? what could be the reason?.

```js
 const today = moment() // let take today is 22 July 2020

const weekStart = today.startOf('week');   // 19th
console.log(weekStart.toString()); // Sun Jul 19 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530

const weekEnd = today.endOf('week');   // 25th
console.log(weekEnd.toString()); // Sat Jul 25 2020 23:59:59 GMT+0530

const validRange = [weekStart,weekEnd]; // should be an array 
console.log(validRange.map(item =>item.toString())); // ["Sat Jul 25 2020 23:59:59 GMT+0530", "Sat Jul 25 2020 23:59:59 GMT+0530"]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Sample output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`moment` dates are mutable (see [the docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/)). This means that when you do the following:

```
const today = moment(); // today = today

const weekStart = today.startOf('week'); // today now equals the start of the week, and
                                         // you've assigned it to a new variable
```

What you want to do instead is:

```
const today = moment(); // today = today

const weekStart = today.clone().startOf('week'); // make a clone of today and then change
                                                 // it to the start of the week
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `.startOf` or `.endOf`, it modifies `today` in place, and returns `today`.  You need to `.clone` the date to get a unique instance of it.

```js
 const today = moment() // let take today is 22 July 2020

const weekStart = today.clone().startOf('week');   // 19th
console.log(weekStart.toString()); // Sun Jul 19 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530

const weekEnd = today.clone().endOf('week');   // 25th
console.log(weekEnd.toString()); // Sat Jul 25 2020 23:59:59 GMT+0530

const validRange = [weekStart,weekEnd]; // should be an array 
console.log(validRange.map(item =>item.toString())); // ["Sat Jul 25 2020 23:59:59 GMT+0530", "Sat Jul 25 2020 23:59:59 GMT+0530"]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The methods `startOf` and `endOf` modify the current object. So you need to instanciate an object for each ones `weekStart` and `weekEnd`.

```js
const today = moment() // let take today is 22 July 2020

const weekStart = moment(today).startOf('week');   // 19th
console.log(weekStart.format()); // Sun Jul 19 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530

const weekEnd = moment(today).endOf('week');   // 25th
console.log(weekEnd.format()); // Sat Jul 25 2020 23:59:59 GMT+0530

const validRange = [weekStart,weekEnd]; // should be an array 

console.log(validRange.map(item =>item.format())); // ["Sat Jul 25 2020 23:59:59 GMT+0530", "Sat Jul 25 2020 23:59:59 GMT+0530"]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```